# Why does my controller keep expecting to retrieve data even though I cleared out the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I am making a rails app, using postgresql as the database, where you can connect with users and message them from their posts. My seeds file creates 10 test users and I was checking out the functionality to message other users but ran out of users to test on so I hopped on the rails console and cleared out the conversations and messages table so I could delete all relations in the database but ever since then I keep getting this error:

```
    ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PagesController#index
    Couldn't find all Private::Conversations with 'id': (14, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 
    10, 11, 1) (found 3 results, but was looking for 10).
```

This is the code in my PagesController index action:

```
def index
    @hobby_posts = Post.by_branch('hobby').limit(8)
    @study_posts = Post.by_branch('study').limit(8)
    @team_posts  = Post.by_branch('team').limit(8)
  end
```

Why does this error keep popping up?

I have tried to completely drop the database, recreate the database, re-run migrations but that doesn't seem to clear out the conversations

this is the code in my ApplicationController:

```rb
def opened_conversations_windows
    if user_signed_in?
      session[:private_conversations] ||= []
      @private_conversations_windows = Private::Conversation.includes(:recipient, :messages)
                                        .find(session[:private_conversations])
    else
      @private_conversations_windows = []
    end
  end
```

the code seems to "work" when I change the if line to

```
if (user_signed_in? && @private_conversations_windows)
```

but when I do this and create a new chat with a user the creation of the new chat relation hits the database but the chat window doesn't show up.
Update:

```
class Private::ConversationsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    recipient_id = Post.find(params[:post_id]).user.id
    @conversation = Private::Conversation.new(sender_id: current_user.id, 
                                             recipient_id: recipient_id)
    if @conversation.save
      Private::Message.create(user_id: current_user.id, 
                              conversation_id: @conversation.id, 
                              body: params[:message_body])

      add_to_conversations unless already_added?

      respond_to do |format|
        format.js {render partial: 'posts/show/contact_user/message_form/success'}
      end
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js {render partial: 'posts/show/contact_user/message_form/fail'}
      end
    end
  end


  def close 
    @conversation_id = params[:id].to_i
    session[:private_conversations].delete(@conversation_id)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js  
    end
  end

  private

  def add_to_conversations
    session[:private_conversations] ||= []
    session[:private_conversations] << @conversation.id
  end

  def already_added?
    session[:private_conversations].include?(@conversation.id)
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`session` variables live for the the duration of the browser session. So this error means that you deleted database records while signed in, and you haven’t adjusted `session[:private_conversations]` appropriately.

You either need to remove the deleted ids from `session[:private_conversations]`, or adjust your find to be okay with only not finding some.

I would change your code to this:

```
def opened_conversations_windows
  if user_signed_in? && session[:private_conversations].present?
    @private_conversations_windows = Private::Conversation.includes(:recipient, :messages)
                                        .where(id: session[:private_conversations])

    # Update the session variable to only have the existing values
    session[:private_conversations] = @private_conversations_windows.map(&:id)
  else
    @private_conversations_windows = []
  end
end
```

Note that I turned `find()` into `where(id: )`. `find` expects that all ids provided will exist. `where` does not require any records to be returned; it just searches and you get what you get.

Additionally, I have it only doing a database query when the user actually has private conversations open. This is important because it would otherwise run the wrong query if you were signed in but had no private conversations. (`WHERE id IS NULL` or something like that)

Lastly, I have it do a little cleanup on the session variable, to set it to only the ones that still exist in the database.

Now later on whenever you set `session[:private_conversations]`, (presumably when someone closes/opens a new conversation) you can set it to only the ones that still exist.

You mention that the following seemed to work:

```
if (user_signed_in? && @private_conversations_windows)
```

Given the code that you posted, I believe you would never actually get `@private_conversations_windows` set to anything other than `[]`. Reason being, you’re currently trying to set that variable, so it should be nil at the moment. Because it’s always nil, you can’t ever fall in to the side of the `if` that actually queries the database. Sure, it won’t error anymore, but that’s because it’s not doing anything useful anymore. It’d basically be equivalent to:

```
def opened_conversations_windows
  @private_conversations_windows = []
end
```

Comment: Yes, that seems to make it work, how would I remove the deleted ids from ````session[:private_conversations]````

Comment: Thanks it works just fine. But just for personal knowledge you had said: You either need to remove the deleted ids from session[:private_conversations], or adjust your find to be okay with only not finding some. How would I delete the id's from session because i had cleared out the database but that didn't seem to work so how would I go about it?

Comment: Right. You didn't post the code ever that sets `session[:private_conversations]` in the first place, so I took the route of being okay with not finding some. If you post that code, I may be able to come up with something else, but I think being a little more loose with the search is wise -- if you were able to find 9/10 of the conversations, I imagine you wouldn't want to 404 the request entirely.

Comment: I updated my question with my code from the Private::Conversations controller

Comment: I see. I thought your controller was deleting the `Private::Conversation` records somewhere. If it were, you would want to remove the id from `session[:private_conversations]` in the same spot. Since it's not really a thing that is supposed to happen, you really have two options: 1.) Clear your session so that it doesn't contain nonexistent conversations 2.) Make the controller okay with some of the conversations not existing (like my code above does)

Comment: How would I clear the session so that it doesn't contain nonexistent conversations?

Comment: Is deleting the `Private::Conversation` records something that happens in the real world?

Comment: Probably doesn't happen

Comment: Then I would personally leave it as is. It should handle the improbable scenario just fine.

Comment: I was just testing the messaging functionality out and now I am getting this error: ````NoMethodError (undefined method `include?' for nil:NilClass):
  
app/controllers/private/conversations_controller.rb:41:in `already_added?'
app/controllers/private/conversations_controller.rb:12:in `create'````

Comment: line 41 in the above conversations controller in ````session[:private_conversations].include?(@conversation.id)```` and line 12 is ````add_to_conversations unless already_added?````

Comment: That’s because you say `add_to_conversations unless already_included?`, however only `add_to_conversations` actually defaults the value to an empty array. This is a problem because `already_added?`, gets called before `add_to_conversations`, but `already_added?` has no default. You need to default to an empty array in `already_added?` as well.